# TypeError: this.parts[1].reviewMoment is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am working on this bug and I keep getting the following error -

```
TypeError: this.parts[1].reviewMoment is not a function
```

I am using jQuery and backbone. Unfortunately, I'm not really familiar with JS and not sure why this line broke.

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "underscore",
], function($, _) {

    reviewMoment: function(place) {
         this.collection.bind("add", _.once(_.bind(this.triggerReview, this)));
         this.collection.addMomentByPlace(place);
     },
     triggerReview: function() {
         this.parts[(this.matchView ? 2 : 1)].reviewMoment();
         if(this.matchView) {
             this.matchView.search.close();
         }
     }
  });
});
```

Why is `reviewMoment` not considered a function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a function because you're not actually creating an object literal `{}` in which you can use the `identifier:property` notation. To create valid function definitions place a return statement with an object literal around your functions:

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "underscore",
], function($, _) {
    return {
        reviewMoment: function(place) {
            this.collection.bind("add", _.once(_.bind(this.triggerReview, this)));
            this.collection.addMomentByPlace(place);
        },
        triggerReview: function() {
            this.parts[(this.matchView ? 2 : 1)].reviewMoment();
            if(this.matchView) {
                this.matchView.search.close();
            }
        }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks -- turns out some code was deleted during some refactoring